# Confused about Powershell parameter documentation

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure if I'm confused about how some of Powershell documentation regarding parameters work, or if the documentation has some mistakes.

For example, the docs for `get-verb` [1] say that for parameter `-Group`, the cmdlet accepts pipeline input, at position 0. However, in the `Inputs` section, it says "None". Also, this doesn't work:

```
"common" | get-verb
```

**Since the docs says that `-Group` accepts pipeline input at position 0, doesn't that imply that the above code should work?**

The docs for `foreach-object` [2] say that for parameter `-InputObject`, the position is "named". However, it accepts the `-InputObject` parameter at position 0.

```
get-service | foreach {$_.name}
```

**Shouldn't that parameter's doc say `Position: 0`?**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-verb?view=powershell-7.3

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: If you are not sure use Format-Table to see properties, it is great at enumerating through objects : get-service | Format-Table.  If you have a group property use get-service | foreach-object { $_.Group }.  I like doing following for debugging : get-service | foreach-object { $_ | Format-Table }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question, the docs are in fact showing inaccurate information and [GitHub Issue #9522](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9522) was raised to correct this.

Looking at `Get-Help` we see the following:

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> Get-Help Get-Verb -Parameter * | Select-Object Name, Position

name  position
----  --------
Group 0
Verb  1
```

Yet, if we look at the autogenerated `param` block using [`ProxyCommand.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#methods):

```bash
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Get-Verb))
```

We can see the following (positions are reversed from what the doc is showing us):

```bash
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]
    ${Verb},

    [Parameter(Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('Common','Communications','Data','Diagnostic','Lifecycle','Other','Security')]
    [string[]]
    ${Group}
)
```

We can also clearly see that `-Verb` is actually position `0` trying positional binding and one valid verb:

```bash
Get-Verb Add
```

As for **`'common' | Get-Verb`** not working, it does as long as we're also binding `-Verb` in the call to the cmdlet, either by value from pipeline by property name or positional binding:

```bash
# All verbs in `Common` groups. Works fine.
# Positional Binding on `-Verb` (Position 0)
'common' | Get-Verb *

# `Add` verb in `Common` groups. Also works fine.
# `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` on both params
[pscustomobject]@{ Group = 'common'; Verb = 'Add' } | Get-Verb
```

---

Regarding the second statement / question:

> ...However, it accepts the `-InputObject` parameter at Position `0`.

This is incorrect, `-InputObject` in fact can be bound either from pipeline or named. **Also note that this parameter is not intended to be used manually in most cases.**

Position `0` is actually the [`-Process` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3#-process) and we can clearly see it by testing this code:

```bash
ForEach-Object { $_ } -InputObject 'hello'
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works: `'common' | Get-Verb *` ; I as read it, that would have tried to bind 'common' at position 0 which, as you demonstrated, is `-Verb`.

Comment: no, position 0 is `*` in this case. `*` is bound to `-Verb` and 'common' is bound by pipeline to `-Group`

Comment: Also, why `get-verb 'add'` works, but `'add' | get-verb` doesn't?

Comment: @Dess that question should be directed to Microsoft not me. This looks like poor design imo.

Comment: Ok, want to make clear that I meant: The ProxyCommand output says that -Verb param is at position 0, and it accepts pipeline input, and that input type is string[]. The design seems ok to me, but still doesn't work, which is weird.

Comment: @Dess I know, I also meant the design of the cmdlet seems off, the design of the param block is ok and `'add' | get-verb` should work imo

Comment: You can have PowerShell show you how your code or other code like ```'common' | Get-Verb``` and ```'common' | Get-Verb *``` is processed/evaluated in real-time by using the cmdlets ```Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer``` and ```Trace-Command```.